# JMeter response time of each thread in InfluxDB

Tags: jmeter, influxdb, grafana

How to get response time in Influxdb of each thread ran in jmeter? I am running a test 20 times, i want to see the response time in Influxdb for all the threads/all the times i am running the test.

[image: Image of Jmeter, running the test case as 20 threads(20 times)]

[image: Influxdb showing the number of threads per second]

[image: Influxdb showing the Max Response times every second]

As you can see i am not getting response time of all my threads, i am getting only the "Max" of the threads that have run in that second using the measurement "jmeter.all.a.max". Is there any way where i can see all the threads response time in Influxdb??

Comment: Without any example inout or output it is impossible to know if your difficulties are due to a misconfiguration, a syntax error, or a fundamental misunderstanding. Can you please provide the actual inputs and outputs you are currently getting, and how they are inadequate?

Comment: @beckettsean: Have added some screenshots in the question, please feel free to ask if you have any other queries. Would be great if you could help. Thank you

Comment: With a `select *` query, you are getting back everything that was written to InfluxDB. I don't know how you are submitting the data from JMeter to InfluxDB, but my guess is that not all the JMeter data is being transmitted. Check your data source, and perhaps check the actual HTTP calls made to 8086 on the InfluxDB server.